# Are projection maps open in the Zariski topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

The projection map $\pi:U\times V\to U$ is an open map if $U$ and $V$are topological spaces and $U\times V$ has the product topology.  Is the same true if $U$ and $V$ are (abstract) varieties with the Zariski topology and $U\times V$ has the product Zariski topology?  And is this a particular example of a more general principle in categorical topology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flat morphisms which are locally of finite presentation are open; this follows from Chevalley's Theorem on the preservation of constructible sets under finitely presented morphisms and the going-down theorem for flat morphisms. See [When is a flat morphism open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676533/when-is-a-flat-morphism-open)

This applies to any projection map $X\times_k Y\to X$ for varieties $X,Y$ over a field $k$.