# Is there an elementary way to prove the set of fibers containing a variety is closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a projective variety, $B$ a projective variety, and $V\subset B\times \mathbb P^n$ a family over $B$. Denote the fiber over a point by $V_b$. Exercise 4.4 in Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course* asks the reader to show the subset

$$\{b \in B : X\subset V_b\}$$

is closed in $B$. This seems to be equivalent to showing that the projection map from the second factor is open. I don't know how to prove that fact without invoking concepts not yet developed in the book ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002582/are-projection-maps-open-in-the-zariski-topology), for example).

Is there an elementary way to do this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that the variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ has no role in the claim we make. So let us try to prove the statement first for a point $x \in \mathbb{P}^n$.
Consider the closed set $F_x = \{(b,x) \mid b \in B \} \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^n$. We have $F_x \cap V = \{(b,x) \mid (b,x) \in V \}$, which is
closed in $F_x$. On the other hand the map $F(x) \rightarrow B$ induced
by projection is a homemorphism. Thus the image of $F(x) \cap B$ in $B$,
which is the set we are interested in, is closed in $B$... call it
$B(x)$. Now we have
$
\{b \in B \mid X \subset V_b \} = \bigcap _{x \in X} B(x) \subset B$
 is closed as it is an intersection of closed sets.